# Zoom in a picturebox image 100 times

Tags: vb.net-2010

I want to zoom In the image of a picturebox which is inside a panel. Basically it's a Radar simulator where I need to show a map on picturebox and zoom it for the range from 100 NM to 1 NM. The zoom value is decided by a HScrollBar (Min-1, Max-100, corresponds to NM). If HScrollbar value is 100 (means 100 NM) , full image is shown without Zoom and when HScrollbar value is 1 (means 1 NM), the image needs to zoom in to 1/100 times smaller area at the center of picture.

In my present code I am increasing the size of the picturebox control and then setting its Left and Top properties to keep it centered. The image size is 577 X 577 and the picturebox size is equal to screen size (i.e maximized). But the problem is that, i am only able to zoom it upto 2.5 times only. More than 2.5 times zooming makes it extremely slow and after sometimes draws the error image i.e. red X mark in the picturebox.

```
 If pb.Image IsNot Nothing Then
        'calculate the new size from the original image size
        Dim nWidth As Integer = CInt((panel1.Width + (100 * panel1.Width / frmLDA.HSRange.Maximum) * (frmLDA.HSRange.Maximum - _scale)))
        Dim nHeight As Integer = CInt((panel1.Height + (100 * panel1.Height / frmLDA.HSRange.Maximum) * (frmLDA.HSRange.Maximum - _scale)))
        newWidth = nWidth
        newHeight = nHeight
        'make sure you do not try to create a new bitmap that has a width or height of 0
        If nWidth > 0 And nHeight > 0 Then
            'create a new bitmap at the new size
            Using bmp As New Bitmap(nWidth, nHeight)
                'create a graphics object for the new bitmap
                Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
                    g.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
                    g.DrawImage(OriginalImage, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight)
                End Using 'disposes the graphics object
                pb.Image.Dispose() 'dispose the old bitmap that was assigned to the image property
                pb.Image = New Bitmap(bmp) 'assign a copy of the new Bitmap
                pb.ClientSize = pb.Image.Size 'reset the size of the picturebox
                pb.Left = CInt(panel1.Width / 2 - pb.Width / 2)
                pb.Top = CInt(panel1.Height / 2 - pb.Height / 2)
            End Using 'disposes the Bitmap
        End If
    End If
```

Is there any way to zoom the image smoothly may be without actually increasing the picturebox size so that it does not encounter any error? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You could scale up your drawing commands or source bitmap instead of the picture box.  If starting up a bitmap you should crop it first or the size will grow too big to work with when you only need a small window.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I understood your point. Can u give any small example code pls or at least brief idea for how to do that?

Comment: If you're using a bitmap, look for an image library.  If drawing things, it's all math -- if a line at scale 10 is (0,0) => (100, 150) then at scale 20 it's (0,0) => (200,300)

Comment: Thank u. I'll try and come back.

Comment: I solved my problem by resizing and relocating Left & Top properties of picturebox and able to zoom from 1 NM to 200 NM. but the problem is other controls like lines and rectangles flicker heavily when zoomed near to maximum value. Tried DoubleBuffered = True but no result. Any idea plz?